# Add an alternate chat to the HUD in minecraft forge

Tags: java, chat, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I am writing a minecraft mod that overlays the chat from external chat services like Skype onto your Minecraft HUD so that you don't have to keep switching applications when you get a new message.

The only problem is I cannot seem to fins a way to add a second chat to the HUD. I have successfully created an alternate chat but I cannot figure out how to add it to the HUD so I can see if the messages I am posting work or not. I have tried searching for things like "make alternate chat minecraft modding" and other similar terms, but all I get is mod showcases and old 1.7 tutorials. (The mod is targeting 1.8.8)

I have also tried looking through the Minecraft code and cant seem to find anything that would add a chat to the HUD. I would appreciate it if someone could point me to a method or mine of code  that i can use to add my alternate chat to the HUD (i was successfully able to do this with a white box...)

Here is my code that is creating the chat

```
GuiNewChat altchat = new GuiNewChat(mc);
altchat.drawChat(1);
String msg = "hi";
this.mc.ingameGUI.getChatGUI().sendChatMessage(msg,true);//displayGuiScreen(altchat);
if (i == 0) {
    altchat.addToSentMessages("test Message to alt chat");
    System.out.println("added message");
    i++;
} else if (i == 100) {
    i = 0;
} else {
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write your own GUI container and then add your render code to render the chat lines.

I suggest you make a copy of the current minecraft chat gui, and implement your own lines for chat source. And choose a different position to render ofcourse.

Don't use the current chat gui. use your own.

```
@SideOnly(Side.CLIENT)
public class TalkGui  extends Gui {
}
```

and add the mandatory methods. But as I said, I suggest you copy over the code in the minecraft chat gui, it has all the neat stuff in there. Just have your own source of display lines for it and set up a handler for lines people type.

This is the most nitty gritty of user interface design in minecraft. You can use buttons and event listeners :-) minecraft has classes for those too.

Comment: So there's no way to do this without creating a completely new chat?

Comment: well, unless you like to abuse reflection into insane levels, it's much easier to make a new chat. It's basically just copy and paste for the most things.

Comment: I would copy from the Gui class? Or GuiNewChat?

Comment: GuiNewChat... gui is just for making a basic overlay.

Comment: Does this work for a new Gui in Minecraft? I want to have three chat boxes on screen for three groups? I created three chatguis for text input but they display on the default GUINewChat? How can i get three GUINewChats on the screen to avoid confusion?